# Linux, safest way to move a file system

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy

I have to move my user home to another device, it occupies several gigabytes, I would like to avoid losing something, at the moment I think I will use rsync `rsync --progress -avh --remove-source-files $SRC/ $DST/`, Is there anything better?

Comment: If you're afraid to lose something, then definitely do _not_ run with `--remove-source-files`.

Comment: I'd also double-quote `"$SRC"` and `"$DST"`. If you've got extended attributes add `-XX`; if you've hard links add `-H`.

Comment: And if you have sparse files add `-S`.  Assuming you didn't use `--remove-source-files`,  you can use the first rsync as a test of the new device and continue using home during the transfer.  Then repeat the rsync again later (add `--delete` to remove files on dest that are no longer on src), and you should see only the few files that changed being copied. Or you can add `-c` and so reread all the files for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @meuh, but I think I will do it from a pendrive with the home not mounted to avoid oddities (or booting as single user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be on the really safe side (depending on your level of paranoia):

1. Burn in the new device
2. Perform surface test of new device
3. Copy files to new device (i.e. not using the option `--remove-source-files`)
4. Mount the new device in its intended place and make sure everything works correctly
5. Only when everything works fine, discard the source files.

In case you would rather keep a backup of the source you could instead of using rsync for copying in point 3 create a tar archive of your home, extract that to the new device, and keep the archive when discarding the old device.

Comment: I used `tar -c | tar -x` in the past but in this case I prefer an incremental copy in case of interruption. I think rsync is the way to go, I was looking for a confirmation, I wanted to understand if there can be problems with named pipes, sockets, symbolic links, hard links, permissions (other unexpected ...).

Comment: In the end I used `rsync -a -H --info=progress2 /src/ /dest/ --delete` (booting in single user) in multiple sessions and everything seems fine, the copy was very slow (the /src/ disk is slow), I spent some time between sessions to delete several cache files from /src/